# OrangePi Zero 3 apparently can't recognize USB Audio Device in Debian 12

Tags: linux, usb, audio, debian

I recently purchased a OrangePi Zero 3 4Gb with expansion board to connect to my Xiegu X6100 ricetrans to run FT8 connections via WSJT-X application.

Unfortunately the connection OrangePi  Zero 3 with X6100 via USB couldn’t work since the OrangePi  Zero 3 recognized the USB Audio Device C-Media Electronics Inc. but the PulseAudio does not since pavucontrol shows a blank page instead of USB Sound Device to be managed.

```
$ dmesg | grep snd
[    6.986750] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [audiocodec     ]: audiocodec - audiocodec
                      audiocodec
1 [ahubdam        ]: ahubdam - ahubdam
                      ahubdam
2 [ahubhdmi       ]: ahubhdmi - ahubhdmi
                      ahubhdmi
3 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB Audio Device
                      C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Audio Device at usb-5200000.usb-1.2, full speed

~$  lsmod | grep snd_usb
snd_usb_audio         278528  0
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_usbmidi_lib        36864  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            40960  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
mc                     53248  6 sunxi_cedrus,videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,videobuf2_common,v4l2_mem2mem

$ ps -A | grep pulse
1613 ?  00:12:16 pulseaudio
```

Despite the USB Audio device is seen by the OPi Zero 3 device, yet it is not regognized by pulseaudio so no audio data can be exchanged between OPi and X6100 rig.

Comment: Weird. "C-Media" chipset are 20+ years old technology, plug'n'play in any modern OS. I use them in Ubuntu, Debian, Deepin, Manjaro and Windows and it always works.

Comment: This problem is not related to Debian 12 itself since all works nicely on i386 Debian 12 on a notebook of mine 12 years old but likely to the OPi Zero 3 Debian 12 kernel implementation that relies on its hw. Unfortunately orangepi support did not answer to this issue.

Comment: Are you using the board headlessly (e.g. ssh)? Please add the output of `ls -l /dev/snd/` and `id`. (Maybe also `loginctl`.)

Comment: At last I understood the reason behind the problem that was the definition of the usb device in /usr/share/alsa-card-profile that was missing. I added the line "load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:3,0" and now all worka fine

Comment: alsa-card-profiles is only needed by pipewire. pulseaudio ships its own set of profile sets and paths files under `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/`. Also only sound card that needs special handling need a profile / path. Sounds more like udev on your system is not working or so (at least not for pulse).